# Unexpected token } jquery

Tags: jquery, function, http, scope

Sorry for this question, it is probably a very stupid mistake.
I am sadly watching for a while but I can not figure out what's wrong.

```
app.controller('studentController', function ($scope, db) {
    $scope.items = null;
    db.getData().then(function (dataResponse) {
        $scope.items = dataResponse;
    }, function () {
        console.log('Shit son');
    })

    $scope.edit = function () {
        $http.post("api/api.php", {
            "categorie": $scope.categorie,
            "action": "edit",
            "id:"
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("Update success");
        });
    }
});
```

My console says that the error is on the line with the success function.

Regards

Comment: If you take the time to format your code correctly errors like this become a lot more obvious. Check the properties/value of the object you're providing to `$http.post`

Answer (score 1):

For the edit method, your data is not correct. You missed to provide value for the `id` property . Also `:` was part of the property name. Try this version. I just hard coded the value of Id property to 2

```
$scope.edit = function(){
    $http.post("api/api.php", 
         { "categorie": $scope.categorie,
           "action": "edit",
           "id": 2
         })
      .success(function(data, status, headers, config)
      {
         console.log("Update success");
      });
};
```

Comment: Thank you i'm sorry wasted your time haha

Answer (score 1):

The value for the parameter id is missing:

```
 "id:"
```

It should be something like

```
 "id": someValue
```